# Extend controller with class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Creating a custom matcher to test certain local variables:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :set_the_local_variable do |variable|    
    match do |actual|
        @actual = controller.binding.local_variable_get(variable)
        @actual == @expected
    end

    failure_message do |actual|
        "set '#{@actual}' equal to #{@expected}. However, it did not: \n '#{@actual.inspect}' \n '#{@expected.inspect}'"
    end

    failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
        "set '#{@actual}' not equal to #{@expected}. However, it did: \n '#{@actual.inspect}' \n '#{@expected.inspect}'"
    end

    description do
        "set the instance '#{@actual}' to equal '#{expected}'"
    end

    def to(expected)
        @expected = expected
        self
    end
end
```

However, this line:

```
 controller.binding.local_variable_get(variable)
```

gives me this error:

```
private method `binding' called for #<StaticController:0x00000104b5a108>
```

How do I get around this? `binding.local_variable_get` works fine in irb:

```
2.1.1 :001 > foo = 'bar'
 => "bar" 
2.1.1 :002 > binding.local_variable_get(:foo)
 => "bar"
```

Could someone explain what's going on here? I understand classes, instances and inheritance and private class methods, but I'm not sure how to get this working.

I'm thinking find out the class which contains binding and extend the controller with that class in the match block? Something like that?

Comment: Why are you testing local variables? Makes for fragile tests and code you can't refactor. Test the side effects like instance variables created `assigns(:inst_variable_name_here)` or redirects, which already have matchers in controller specs.

Comment: I know, I'm not testing every single variable (mental) just this one hash I really want to test.

Comment: Can you extract it into a service object and unit test it there instead? My kneejerk reaction is that you're essentially monkeypatching rspec instead of testing on the right level for what you are looking to accomplish. Either way, best of luck.

Comment: I think you're right and while I could make it a helper, I'm only using it in one place. It's not a huge issue. If I get an answer I'll see what happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `binding` says:

> Returns a Binding object, describing the variable and method bindings
>   *at the point of call*.

(emphasis added)

Try this in IRB:

```
> self
main
> binding
=> #<Binding:0x007fa89a8be670>
> self.binding
NoMethodError: private method `binding' called for main:Object
```

You can of course send the message directly:

```
> self.send(:binding)
=> #<Binding:0x007fa89a890b30>
```

but that's the same thing as typing in `binding`.

What you type in IRB is done in the context of the top-level `main` method. When you execute `controller.binding`, you are calling the method on the test controller instance that RSpec creates for you. However, the context is the RSpec example instance, not the controller instance, which is (probably?) not what you wanted.

Really though this is all academic: it is not wise to reach into instances and inspect the value of local variables when testing. If you are strongly tempted to do so, it is IMHO an indication that some refactoring is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Not an issue at all, but I am a bit curious has to how local variable testing could be done. How could you send `binding.local_variable_get()` to the controller? This, `controller.send(:binding).send(:local_variables)` returns the local variables in the actual matcher (`actual` and `variable`) I didn't know that rspec creates another instance of the controller. Why wouldn't the local variables in the controller be present in the rspec instance?

Comment: RSpec does not create a separate controller instance, sorry if I was confusing on that point. What I was trying to get at is that calling `controller.send(:binding)` brings back the same context as calling `binding` in the context of the example, which is the same effect you see when calling it in the matcher. This might seem counterintuitive, but it makes sense because `Binding` encapsulates the context at the point where it is called, not on some point in the receiver. Eg. try `controller.send(:binding).eval('controller')` --returns the same instance, right?